# Download parallel from multiple peers on UDP

Tags: tcp, stream, udp

TCP is very good protocol but it take too much time to establish a connection and isn't working so well with parallel downloading.

I'm looking for a UDP-based protocol that make it possible to stream a file in parallel from multiple peers an once.

Is there is anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

[*µ*TP (Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol) seems like what you need.

> **Micro Transport Protocol** or ***µ*TP** (sometimes also **uTP**) is an [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_standard) [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)-based variant of the [BitTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)) [peer-to-peer file sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer_file_sharing) [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(computing)) intended to mitigate poor latency and other [congestion control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_congestion#Congestion_control) issues found in conventional BitTorrent over TCP, while providing reliable, ordered delivery.